# Updating thing-shadow on aws-iot using Node.js getting some error..also attached code for reffrence

Tags: node.js, aws-iot

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

    var myThingName = 'pi_2';
var fs, configurationFile;

    configurationFile = './configuration.json';
    fs = require('fs');
    var args = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configurationFile));
var thingShadows = awsIot.thingShadow({

   keyPath: args.privateKey,
   certPath: args.clientCert,
   caPath: args.caCert,
   clientId: myThingName,
   region: args.host

});

thingShadows
  .on('connect', function() {

    console.log('connect');
device.subscribe('topic_1');


    device.publish('topic_2', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 1}));
    });
```

while doing this got error:-

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>       at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
>       at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)

Comment: Here I got answer!!! I just changed the region us-east-1(N.Virginia) to eu-west-1(Ireland). This error occurs due to server is busy or not responding from this time.. and also add new certificates in my program

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code for updating thing shadows on aws-iot:-

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var myThingName = 'pi_2';
var thingShadows =awsIot.thingShadow({
keyPath: './private.pem.key',
certPath: './certificate.pem.crt',
caPath: './root-CA.crt',
clientId: myThingName,
region: 'ap-southeast-1'
});
mythingstate = {
"state": {
"reported": {
  "ip": "sagar"//update your state here.
}`}`}`

thingShadows.on('connect', function() {
console.log("Connected...");
console.log("Registering...");
thingShadows.register( myThingName);
```

//An update right away causes a timeout error, so we wait about 2 seconds

```
setTimeout( function() {
console.log("Updating my IP address...");
clientTokenIP = thingShadows.update(myThingName, mythingstate);
console.log("Update:" + clientTokenIP);
}, 2500 );
// Code below just logs messages for info/debugging
thingShadows.on('status',function(thingName, stat, clientToken,
stateObject) {
console.log('received '+stat+' on '+thingName+':
'+JSON.stringify(stateObject));
});
thingShadows.on('update',function(thingName, stateObject) {
console.log('received update '+' on '+thingName+': '+`JSON.stringify(stateObject));
});
thingShadows.on('delta',function(thingName, stateObject) {
console.log('received delta '+' on '+thingName+': '+`JSON.stringify(stateObject));`});`

thingShadows.on('timeout',`function(thingName, clientToken) {`
console.log('received timeout for '+ clientToken)`});`

thingShadows.on('close', function() {`
console.log('close');
});

thingShadows`.on('reconnect', function() {`
console.log('reconnect');
});

thingShadows`.on('offline', function() {
console.log('offline');
});

thingShadows`.on('error', function(error) {
console.log('error', error);
});`});`
```